# laravel blade 2Dim array output

Tags: php, html, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

This is something that I really should be getting right. But I for some reason cannot get it to work.

In my controller I have code like this

```
$challenges = \DB::table('challenges')->get();
echo print_r($challenges);
return view('challenge.ViewChallenges.ChallengeList',compact('challenges'));
```

The echo prints the 2 rows out of my database onto the page like so

`Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [Name] => ian [Description] => desc1 [StartDate] => 2017-07-07 [SubmissionDate] => 2017-07-14 [Active] => 1 [Requirements] => qwerty [SubmissionCap] => 3 [DataUsage] => 4 [created_at] => 2017-07-08 20:00:08 [updated_at] => 2017-07-08 20:00:08 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [Name] => ggggggggggggg [Description] => dfsdfs [StartDate] => 2017-07-21 [SubmissionDate] => 2017-07-28 [Active] => 1 [Requirements] => req sum [SubmissionCap] => 56 [DataUsage] => 78 [created_at] => 2017-07-08 20:00:36 [updated_at] => 2017-07-08 20:00:36 ) ) ) 1`

In my view I can loop through each entry using this

```
@foreach($challenges as $challenge)
   @foreach($challenge as $item)
      {{$item}}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I have tried loads of things to get for instance just the Name, but it seems like I might be overlooking something small somewhere. I have looked though very simular questions on here but it does not seem to solve my issue. Maybe $challenges is not really a 2 dim array?

Comment: Just replace with:`@foreach($challenges as $challenge)
   {{$challenge->name}}
@endforeach`

Comment: Yes, working! thank you